# How to unpack and read android ABD file system image file on 20.04 LTS

Tags: android, adb

One of the "editors/moderators(?)" of this list insists that I start with:

Begin with file samsung-a51-5g.adb. Edit your question to add the info, don't respond in comments. – waltinator 1 hour ago

I did this before posting (a standard text screen systems "management" command, along with `du`, `ls -la`, and other commands), but the editor wants the result:

`samsung-a51-5g.ab: Android Backup, version 5, Compressed, Not-Encrypted`

Had I found a utility for "Android Backup, version 5, Compressed" I would not have posted the question.  The editor also removed the tag concerning "android-tools-adb" that only complicates the search on this list for an answer -- these are the only tools I have found for Linux, and others using this tool set may have the same question.  However, on this list, the "moderator" or "editors" rule, assuming that even an experienced systems internals person (such as myself) cannot properly pose a question.  I truly miss the likes of the Scientific Linux list with respect to Ubuntu LTS (not Ubuntu "enthusiast").  I am certain that the "editor/s" will remove the above comment as irrelevant.

I am able to create an image of the "complete" file system of an Android device ("smart phone") on a linux system using, eg,

```
sudo apt-get install android-tools-adb`
adb devices
adb backup samsung-a51-5g.ab -apk -all
```

The file `samsung-a51-5g.ab` exists after the above,`ls -la` outputs a size of 208709453, and supposedly is related to a compressed tar format file.  How does one decompress this file on the linux side so that one can actually read the files?  Is there a "graphical" tool equivalent to `adb`?

Addition:  I have found [How to fully backup non-rooted devices?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28296/how-to-fully-backup-non-rooted-devices)

and it turns out (according to the above) a full backup (image of entire "filesystem") is not possible unless the device is "rooted" (so that "su" will work).  "Rooting" will invalidate the manufacturer's warranty -- at least for a Samsung android "smart phone".  Note also that the above URL mostly refers to the use of the tools under MS Windows, not Linux, and not Ubuntu LTS specific.

Comment: Begin with `file samsung-a51-5g.adb`. [Edit] your question to add the info, don't respond in comments.

Comment: Evidently https://github.com/nelenkov/android-backup-extractor/releases/tag/20210409062249-e30cc24 contains the solution.  I plan to test this solution and will report what I find.

Comment: The immediately preceding URL contains a file `abe.jar` .  Using `java -jar ~/Downloads/android/abe/abe.jar unpack ./samsung-a51-5g-back.ab ./samsung-a51-5g-back.tar`  , and using the directory path/s appropriate for the system in use (the above are "mine"), `abe.jar` converts an `ab` file into a `tar` file that can be accessed with the ordinary `tar` command.  I have just done this. Presumably, an industrious person could convert the above text terminal command/s into a nice GUI that would allow one to choose the `ab` file and the select the output directory for the `tar` file.